# Did someone arrange rocks in a U shape?

Tags: the-revenant

In The Revenant (2015), there's a scene where Leo finds fish in the river and the fish is trapped in rocks which are arranged in a U shape on the side of the river. So did someone arrange the rocks in a U shape or were they natural arranged?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

He made that rock formation himself to catch fish.

The arrangement of rocks into that shape is a traditional fishing technique called a *fishing weir*. Quite a few Native American tribes used this kind of fishing technique to catch freshwater fish. The rock formation forces the fish swimming downstream into a small area where they can't easily escape, and can be grabbed by the person fishing.

From what I've read, it's actually not likely that a real fisherman would have used a weir in such a shallow stream; in those cases you could typically just grab the fish by hand as they swam in front of you. Nonetheless, it is a valid fishing technique in other cases.

Comment: Could be that he did it because he was too weak and like this would be easier to catch the fish?

Comment: The problem is, as I understand it, that "fish tickling" (holding your hand underwater and waiting for a fish to swim over it) is both more common in shallow water and uses far less energy to do. I suspect the filmmakers were worried that people wouldn't buy it as "real enough" , or else wanted to play up Glass's survival skills